# sed remove last instance of a character via pipe?

Tags: sed

I have a generated json array in a multi-line variable, but I need to remove the last comma like in `[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},]`, independently from the formatting, newlines or whitespaces.

I'm trying to use the answers from [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162379/16792) but I'm using a variable rather than a file as input:

For example the sed version:

```
echo "$json" | sed -n 'x;${s/,$//;p;x}; 2,$ p'
```

I'm trying the same with the `awk` example with no success.

The only answer I could get working with the pipe is further down on the page with perl `echo "$json" | perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(.*),(.*?)/\1\2/s'`.

I'd prefer to use `sed` instead of `perl` as the [local settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-to-fix-a-locale-setting-warning-from-perl) for `perl` aren't always setup on the machines I manage.

How can I modify the sed command to use with a pipe?

Comment: the title says *remove last instance* - what is that instance?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it's dynamically generated array/json where the last object is followed by a `,` ... for example `[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},]` the `,` after object c needs to be removed.

Comment: Well `,]` does not match `,$` - the question you linked is specifically about removing a comma as the last character on a line

Comment: @steeldriver oops I missed that. I'm trying to remove it regardless of location. Should I close and open a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That (brilliant btw) answer you took is for changes on the next-to-last line only.

If you only have one line, it's much easier; like @I_GNU_it_all_along suggested to replace `,]` by `]`:

```
echo "$json" | sed 's/,]/]/'
```

or, the general solution to remove the last instance of a character in a file with GNU `sed`:

```
echo "$json" | sed -z 's/\(.*\),/\1/'
```

What does it do? The `-z` option tells `sed` to process the whole buffer at once instead of line-by-line, so we simply can replace the last comma in the buffer.

Unfortunally, you can easily remove the first comma (`s/,//`) or the 42th comma (`s/,//42`) but not the last comma (something like `s/,//$` is not implemented).

So we take advantage of the "greedy" `*`: `.*` will match as many characters as possible, so `.*,` will match all chars upto the last comma. But we want to remove the last comma only, so we surround everything else with `\(\)` and can reuse that part in the replacement as `\1`.

If you don't have the `-z` option in your `sed`, you have to manually collect all lines in the buffer:

```
echo "$json" | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\(.*\),/\1/'
```

Comment: Not perfect but it works. `"$json"` actually has multiple lines so it doesn't work. As a work around I just removed the quotes and used `echo $json` in combination with your second answer. Which output valid json.

Comment: Just for future, if you changed `sed 's/,]/]/'` to `sed 's/,]/]/g'` it would apply globally rather than just stop at the first instance (which should deal with it not just being on 1 line).

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Sorry, I misunderstood. I edited the answer to deal with multi-line input.

Comment: @Philippos thanks for the update. That will be a big help as I often find myself having to generate json this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace the instance of `,]` with `]`?

```
echo "$json" | sed 's/,]/]/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON-specific issue: if the last array item is followed by comma `,` any JSON validator will throw an error telling that it's `Expected another array element at line ...`.

Try **awk** solution:

Sample json file `input.json` (invalid):

```
[
  {
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "keys": [
        1,2,3,
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "c"
  },
]
```

---

```
awk -v RS= '{ gsub(/,[[:space:]]*]/, "\n]", $0) }1' input.json | jq '.'
```

The output (piped with **jq**):

```
[
  {
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "keys": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "c"
  }
]
```